# Is it possible to configure React application to use container's environment variables in Kubernetes?

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, containers

To begin with - let us suppose we have a React application. We want to build it and deploy to 3 environments - dev, test and production. As every front-end app it needs to call some APIs. API addresses will vary between the environments. So they should be stored as environment variables.

As every modern, progressive developer we want to use containers. In particular Kubernetes.

We want to build our web application and deploy it on K8S cluster. The container image should be built and kind of sealed for changes, then before deployment to each particular environment the variables should be injected.

But it seems there's one great impossibility here. When it comes to .NET apps for example, when we have .dll compiled, it reads a config file in the runtime. It's not a case with React. After we generate build we have just static files. The variables are changed to static values in the process of building React app. It seems there's no way to update it after that point - or is it?

Comment: As other have mentioned.  You want to take advantage of K8 "ConfigMaps" and "Secrets".  You can inject those as Environment variables or "virtual text files".  I prefer "virtual text files" over environment variables for secrets so "loggers" don't log the secrets (when dumping all the env variables).  So you write some basic code to read these values (configmap or secrets) that are "mounted" when a pod comes up...

Comment: See this article into my point about a "secret" as an environment variable : https://techbeacon.com/devops/how-keep-your-container-secrets-secure

Comment: Please take a look at this: [Kubernetes: services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to solve your problem is not correct.

You don't need to know anything about the addresses of the backend services in your react app. Only the frontend server/gateway that is serving your react app needs to know about the backend services. Any request from the react app should be proxied via the gateway.

See API gateway pattern - https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Comment: That can be some solution. So you mean we should call to API gateway instead of separate APIs. But how we know which environment API GW we should call?

Comment: From react point of view, it doesn't need to know what environment it is in. React app always makes request to same server- `axios.get("/api/v1")`. It is the user who connects to the environment he wants by typing in the URL of the appropriate server.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand.

Comment: If i want to connect to my app in production environment, I connect to `http://prod:8080`. If I want to connect to my in QA environment, I connect to `http://qa:8080`. In both the cases, same react app loads in my browser served from these serves. When the react app makes a get request with the code `axios.get("/api/v1")`, it goes to `http://prod:8080/api/v1` in first case and `http://qa:8080/api/v1` in second case. `http://prod:8080/` server or `http://qa:8080/` gateway servers take care of making backend API calls to appropriate backend services and forward the request.

Comment: Well, URLs of frontend and backend aren't the same in non prod environment in our case...

Comment: The backend URLs can be anything. They can be easily configured on the gateway servers. If your api server is at a URL `my-qa-api:9000`, then when the request `http://qa:8080/api/v1` is made by the client(your react app), the `qa:8080` gateway forwards it to `http://my-qa-api:9000/api/v1` and then sends the response back to client. The URl `my-qa-api:9000` is a configuration to the gateway `qa:8080` which can be set as environment variable for example.

Comment: But anyway it's good idea. If we tinker with the routes it can be useful. However I think that there can be different needs for environment variables usage, so I'll keep the answer open...

Comment: Sure np. Actually this is even simpler than you might be thinking. I'm not sure if you have already containerised your services or not but once you do your backend URLs actually don't need to changed even though your are running multiple environments i.e., both your QA environment's backend API service and prod environment's API service can be made accessible at same URL - `http://api-server:9000` for example. This is achieved by running the services related to prod and services related to QA under their own docker bridge networks (or under same namespace if you are running on kubernetes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [config map](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-a-container-environment-variable-with-data-from-a-single-configmap) to store the API endpoint address and refer it as environment variable in the pod.

If you want to change some values while the pod is running you can mount the config map and any change to it will be [synced in the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically)

Comment: You can read these variables in the pod, but you can't update React build based on this variables (without producing new build).